# Creating/removing divs using checkbox filter

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

Ideally when whichever group's checkbox is checked, divs are created repping the animals of that group and when unchecking whichever group, the divs of that group are removed. My problem is whenever I uncheck one group, it removes the divs from all groups along with the container, and prevents the method for creating divs from working again if rechecked. Why is this and how do I fix it? Thanks.

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('cont');
    
function test(x) {
    var selected = x.checked;
    if (selected == true) {
        array.forEach(function(element) {
            if (element.sort == x.id) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = x.id;
                var header = document.createElement('h4');
                header.innerHTML = element.title;
                div.appendChild(header);
                cont.appendChild(div);
            }   
        })
    }   
    if (selected == false) {
        var zed = cont.getElementsByClassName(x.id);
        cont.remove(zed); 
    }
}
    

var array = [ 
    {title: 'Shark', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Whale', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Tuna', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Cow', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Sheep', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Chicken', sort: 'Farm'},
]
```

```css
.results-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color:lightskyblue;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    
    .results-container div {
        display: flex;
        background-color: white; 
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='filter-container'>
    Sea: <input type="checkbox" id = 'Sea' onClick="test(this)" />
    Farm: <input type="checkbox" id="Farm" onClick="test(this)"/>
</div>
    
<div id='cont' class='results-container'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your code and found a few problems:

- You set the id of multiple elements to the same value. An `id` should be unique. I changed it to name.
- Your query selector tries to match the id, but misses the # for it, see the [CSS Query Selector Specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). I used a class property to select multiple elements.
- You call the remove method, which will remove that element. You need to loop through the NodeList and remove each child that matches the selector.

Here is a fixed code:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('cont');
    
function test(x) {
    var selected = x.checked;
    if (selected == true) {
        array.forEach(function(element) {
            if (element.sort == x.name ) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute("class", x.name)
                var header = document.createElement('h4');
                header.innerHTML = element.title;
                div.appendChild(header);
                cont.appendChild(div);
            }   
        })
    }   
    if (selected == false) {
        var zed = cont.querySelectorAll('.'+x.name);
        zed.forEach(el => cont.removeChild(el))
    }
}
    

var array = [ 
    {title: 'Shark', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Whale', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Tuna', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Cow', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Sheep', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Chicken', sort: 'Farm'},
]
```

```css
.results-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color:lightskyblue;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    
    .results-container div {
        display: flex;
        background-color: white; 
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='filter-container'>
    Sea: <input type="checkbox" name = 'Sea' onClick="test(this)" />
    Farm: <input type="checkbox" name="Farm" onClick="test(this)"/>
</div>
    
<div id='cont' class='results-container'></div>
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks for the explanation and solution. Appreciate it muffin.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('cont');


var array = [ 
    {title: 'Shark', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Whale', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Tuna', sort: 'Sea'},
    {title: 'Cow', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Sheep', sort: 'Farm'},
    {title: 'Chicken', sort: 'Farm'},
]

$('.commonInput').on('click', function(){
  cont.innerHTML = "";
   $('.commonInput').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop("checked")==true){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       array.forEach(function(element) {
            if (element.sort == id) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute('class', id);
                var header = document.createElement('h4');
                header.innerHTML = element.title;
                div.appendChild(header);
                cont.appendChild(div);
            }   
        });
     }else{
       var removeElm = $(this).attr('id');
       $('.'+removeElm).remove();
       console.log(removeElm);
       
     }     
   });
});
```

```css
.results-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color:lightskyblue;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    
    .results-container div {
        display: flex;
        background-color: white; 
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='filter-container'>
    Sea: <input type="checkbox" id = 'Sea' class="commonInput" />
    Farm: <input type="checkbox" id="Farm" class="commonInput"/>
</div>
    
<div id='cont' class='results-container'></div>
```

Check some jQuery solution